# Clonezilla: realiable alternative

Tags: partitioning, backup, restore, clonezilla

Does anybody knows a good alternative to clonezilla to clone the whole disk like in clonezilla?

Thanks.

Comment: It may be useful if you say why you need an alternative. Why is clonezilla is not adequate? Are you looking for certain features that clonezilla does not have?

Comment: Just looking for alternatives that's all :)

Comment: There is a fork of clonezilla called Rescuezilla that is compatible with clonezilla archives. If you dual boot Macrium Reflect Free is a reliable choice. It’s free as the name suggests. Most disk drive manufacturers offer free disk cloning software